# Skype wont load on 12.10

Tags: 12.10, skype

I installed Skype onto my laptop and it wont start at all. I Installed it from the Ubuntu Software Center.  Not sure what I did wrong.  Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Your question does not list any details and it's very hard to answer it in the current state. Can you at least provide some details like the following: Skype version (`dpkg -l skype*` - or use your package management tool) What error output do you get if you run `skype` in a terminal?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue:

```
pst007x@pst007x-Serval-Professional:~$ dpkg -l skype*
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version      Architecture Description
+++-==============-============-============-=================================
ii  skype          4.1.0.20.0-0 amd64        client for Skype VOIP and instant
ii  skype-bin      4.1.0.20.0-0 i386         client for Skype VOIP and instant
un  skype-common   <none>                    (no description available)
un  skype-mid      <none>                    (no description available)
un  skype4pidgin   <none>                    (no description available)
pst007x@pst007x-Serval-Professional:~$
```

I could not launch from the icon in the Unity bar after install, but could launch it from terminal... I recreated the Skype launcher, using a Menu editor, and all worked ok after that.... just a strange glitch... :-/